# Handling more projects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I have 2 TypeScript projects. One project is the main product, the other one is a project which include demo files:

```
myProject
+-src
| +-file1.ts
| +-...
| +-myProject.tsconfig
+-demo
  +-demoFile1.ts
  +-...
```

`myProject.ts` makes sure that all stuff is properly built into JavaScript and is working fine. The file looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "module": "amd",
        "outDir": "../out"
    },
    "files": [
        "file1.ts",
        "file2.ts",
        ...
    ]
}
```

#### Building demo files

I want to create `demo/myProjectDemo.tsconfig` for my demos as well, however this should reference `myProject.tsconfig` as those demo files will reference files in the project.

The goal is being able to build the product and demos separately. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal is being able to build the product and demos separately. How to do this?

Just plain using `tsc -p` on the command line can do this. Just add the files you need from the project in the `myProjectDemo.tsconfig`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "module": "amd",
        "outDir": "../out"
    },
    "files": [
        "demoFile.ts",
        "../src/file1.ts",
        ...
    ]
}
```

## More

You will have a hard time with IDEs ([added a project switch](https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/tree/master/docs/features#project-search) to unreleased [alm.tools](http://alm.tools/))

Comment: So I will need to rewrite all the files in `myProject.tsconfig` into `myProjectDemo.tsconfig`? Wished I could avoid this... Like does `.tsconfig` file support the ability to reference an external json file?

Comment: Nested tsconfig file imports aren't supported. Things will get better once there is `filesGlob` support though : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md#filesglob

Comment: Yes, had no time for trying out, had some other stuff to do. As soon as I try this and works I will mark it :)